# Please add more space around code or quote blocks in lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, markdown-rendering, list

Since a CSS update a while ago, code blocks and quotes in lists are too close to the line above for comfort:

1. This is a code example. Particularly annoying with `code spans` in the line.

   ```
   Example code
   Foo Bar
   ```
2. This is a quote example.

   > Example Quote
   >
   > Foo Bar

Without the lists, the gap is significantly greater:

This is a code example. Particularly annoying with `code spans` in the line.

```
Example code
Foo Bar
```

This is a quote example.

> Example Quote
>
> Foo Bar

A screenshot of the above, in case it's a local issue:

[image]

The code span seems to have no visual separation from the code block below it. I have even seen cases where a user added `<br>` to keep a gap between a code block and the line above, while retaining indentation.

Comment: It takes **two** `<br>`s to make it look good at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed, it will be live after our next production build.

Comment: Yay! Thanks for fixing this!